# Completely Uninstall Pycharm 3.4 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, ide

I am using Pycharm 3.4 community edition which does not upgrade to the latest version of the IDE. I want to completely uninstall Pycharm 3.4 and reinstall 4.x.x version. I installed it form `.tar.gz` file. Which directory is to be deleted for uninstalling pycharm without harming the current projects?

Comment: I have deleted 2 directories. One is pycharm-community-3.x.x which was the extracted folder of the `tar.gz` file. and another directory is ~/.Pycharm30. Seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, there are only two things to do:

- Delete the `pycharm-community-3.4.X` folder (installation files) that you extracted from the .tar.gz
- Delete the `~/.PyCharm30` folder (configuration files)

You can see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) that PyCharm doesn't put any more files than that in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and use the below command which will open the pycharm from bin,

```
sudo ./pycharm.sh
```

Once it gets opened, create a desktop entry with the help of 'Tools". This will help to create a file in desktop. After file created in desktop right click and delete the pycharm file. This will help you to delete pycharm without giving any effect to the current projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not applicable to your case, but in the future, you may want to install PyCharm via the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/). Not only it will let you install upgrades easily, but you can also uninstall PyCharm at the click of a button.